# T-SQL stored procedure returns table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

How do I make a T-SQL stored procedure that returns the (tabular) result of this SELECT statement:

```
USE automation

SELECT insurer.name,
insurer.case_name,
contact.name,
contact_address.line_1,
contact_address.city,
state.state_abbr,
contact_address.zip

FROM person as insurer

INNER JOIN persons_relationship on persons_relationship.person2_id = insurer.person_id
INNER JOIN person contact on contact.person_id = persons_relationship.person_id
INNER JOIN person_address contact_person_address on contact_person_address.person_id = contact.person_id
INNER JOIN address contact_address on contact_address.address_id = contact_person_address.address_id
INNER JOIN state on state.state_id = contact_address.state_id

insurer.person_class_id = 2
```

Answer (score 1):

Do something like this:

```
USE Automation
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProcedureNameHere
AS
   SELECT 
       insurer.name,
       insurer.case_name,
       contact.name,
       contact_address.line_1,
       contact_address.city,
       state.state_abbr,
       contact_address.zip
   FROM 
       person as insurer
   INNER JOIN 
       persons_relationship on persons_relationship.person2_id = insurer.person_id
   INNER JOIN 
       person contact on contact.person_id = persons_relationship.person_id
   INNER JOIN 
       person_address contact_person_address on contact_person_address.person_id = contact.person_id
   INNER JOIN 
       address contact_address on contact_address.address_id = contact_person_address.address_id
   INNER JOIN 
       state on state.state_id = contact_address.state_id
```

and you're done. Now you can call your statement as:

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'dbo.YourProcedureNameHere'
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you chose to use `sp_executesql` over `EXEC dbo.YourProcedureNameHere`. Is there a good reason, or just personal preference?

Comment: @Cory: it's the preferred way of doing it, because it would allow you to specify parameters for the stored procedure (here, there are none, of course). See [Kimberly Tripp's blog post on how EXEC and sp_executesql are different](http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/kimberly/exec-and-sp_executesql-how-are-they-different/) and why `sp_executesql` is the preferred way to go

Comment: I'm used to seeing `sp_executesql` used under the hood in certain data mappers and other ORMs, but I never thought to use it outright in basic stored procedure execution. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you also put

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
```

Straight after the **AS**. Some data access libraries are confused by the *x records affected* message and this turns it off.

Answer (score -1):

put this query in the stored procedure and when you will run this stored procedure you will get tabular result